# Android Media player/framework species

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm confused about species of media player/framework/library of Android and it's role and positions.

Here is my understanding about Android media player and framework.
[image]

I don't have confident what I understand, still be under the chaos.

From [Android developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview),
for application side: apk uses Application Framework which has two players - MediaPlayer, ExoPlayer

for Native framework side: it has also various players - Nu, awesome, etc.

There're some query for **gstreamer vs ffmpeg**, **ffmpeg vs vlc**, or **exoplayer vs vitamio**.  It makes me more confusing.

Would you clearify me to get the right concept for them?
If my android custom device use ffmpeg, that means it doesn't use standard Android media framework?

For stagefright engine, there is no alternative for this?